# Do I need 2 Android SDKs?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I have 2 Android SDKs on my machine:
D:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk
D:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

I had explicitly installed the first one, but I don't know where the second came from. All the Android Studio projects I have refer to the 2nd one in their `local.properties` file.

Did this 2nd one get installed with Android Studio?
Do I need this 1st one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio did install the second one on its own and unless you need the first one for any reason (such as `adb` is in your PATH or other projects reference it), you can safely delete it.

Comment: Ohhh... your words have sparked my memory. I had been developing Android apps in Eclipse, then moved to Android Studio a while back. The Eclipse Android projects use the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

YEs...Android studio comes with its copy of sdk bundle